# How to install module magento 2 don't need run command line bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, hosting, command-line

I need to install module pf magento 2 in hosting. I'm trying to connect host with port 21 using putty but not success. I need one other way, please help me.

Comment: see here https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-modules-extensions.html

Comment: [Web Setup Wizard](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/compman-checklist.html) should work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function will be your friend, if you don't have permission of CLI.

To use this function , just simple create new file in your root server(Let's call it `custom.php`), then write below code in this file

`system('php bin/magento cache:status');` // you can change it to your command

And run this script with `http://your base url/custom.php`

It will gives you resulted output.

---

You have also second option if you run magento2 command without CLI , but it doesn't gives you any message(I mean success or fail), but you can use if you don't have any option.

For that you have to create a new file(Let's call it `custom1.php`), and write below code in your file.

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$k[0]='bin/magento';
$k[1]='cache:status'; // write your proper command like setup:upgrade,cache:enable etc...
$_SERVER['argv']=$k;
try {
    $handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
    set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
    $application = new Magento\Framework\Console\Cli('Magento CLI');
    $application->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    while ($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
        echo "\n\n";
        $e = $e->getPrevious();
    }
}
```

---

And run this script with `http://your base url/custom1.php`

---

I know this is very dirty way, but you can use if you want.

Comment: could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694678/active-an-extension-based-on-condition-in-magento-2

Comment: could you please help to sort out the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can install Magento 2 extension manually

1. Download the extension
2. Unzip the file in a temporary directory
3. Upload it to your Magento installation root directory
4. Disable the cache under System­ > Cache Management

Edit `app/etc/config.php` file and three line code:

```
‘Ves_All’ => 1,
‘Ves_Megamenu’ => 1,
‘Ves_Setup’ => 1,
```

5. Now Disable the cache under System > Cache Management
6. After opening Stores ­> Configuration­ > Advanced­ > Advanced, the module will be shown in the admin panel.

You can see this article as reference

[**http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/quick-tour/install-extension.html**](http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/quick-tour/install-extension.html)