# Execute magento commands in php shell without SSH

Tags: magento2, command-line, ssh

My webserver host does not provide access to SSH.

I want to run commands like:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I have tried to do this in the shell terminal using:
- phpFileManager
- eXtplorer
But none of them seem to work.

When I run the command nothing happens, and there is no output to the console:
[image: Magento command no output]

Can this even work in a shell, or do I need to have SSH access?

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

[How to install module magento 2 don't need run command line bin/magento setup:upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125064/how-to-install-module-magento-2-dont-need-run-command-line-bin-magento-setupup/125090#125090)

This is not a good way but if you have not SSH then you can use it if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Execute command localy and put genereated files from pub/* and var/* to server

Comment: Ok, I will try that. What about commands like "magento setup:upgrade" to update the database for modules?

Comment: You can run this command in magento updater application

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perfect solution. Even if system() and shell_exec() and other commands are disabled from server due to security reasons, this script will help you to execute commands.

Note : It will not give any output but it will execute the command successfully.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$k[0]='bin/magento';
$k[1]='setup:upgrade'; // You can change command as you want like setup:static-content:deploy, cache:status etc.
$_SERVER['argv']=$k;
try {
$handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
$application = new Magento\Framework\Console\Cli('Magento CLI');
$application->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
while ($e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
echo $e->getTraceAsString();
echo "\n\n";
$e = $e->getPrevious();
}
}
?>
```