# run php shell commands

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, command-line, shell

I put my Magento website in a not dedicated server.
So, everytime I want to run some php shell commands I have to write an email to my WebHosting tutor and tell him wich commands he has to execute.
Wait for the answer and lost a lot of time..
Is there any way to this alone?

Thanks

Comment: The host does not offer ssh access?

Comment: Web hosting tutor infers that you have a person hosting your website, instead of a company? If yes, you will need to work with them... they COULD possibly grant you SSH access.

Comment: no, they don't. He says me "for security reasons".

Comment: This link helps you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125064/how-to-install-module-magento-2-dont-need-run-command-line-bin-magento-setupup/125090#125090

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a host who just gives you web hosting and not SSH (I assume this is the case or the point of your question would be nullified) then you'll almost certainly find you cannot run them as the host will have configured it this way.

It is worth noting also that if you are on a cPanel host, whilst they may offer ssh access php execution will definitely be disabled still with no ability to enable.

Finally, if it's just a case of your tutor hosts his own server you'll find he can enable the execution of shell commands within php, however again if he were to do this... he may as well just GIVE you shell access.

Comment: they tell me I cold not execute commands because on the server there are other websites.

Comment: I expected as much. I'm afraid there is no workaround