# style is not working at all front & backend

Tags: magento-2.1.7, styles

I have moved Magento 2.1.7 website to another host and domain.

I have correctly configured everything and it's working normally and now i'm on `maintenance mode`.

Style is not working on front and backend and the browser is giving alot of errors while loading resources and it's while viewing the website normally or on maintenance mode.

[image: Frontend]

[image: Backend]

I have also tried to changing `/symlink` into .../copy from di.xml file but nothing happened.

anyone please help ????

Comment: Did you run upgrade command and other commands ?

Comment: i couldn't use shell commands i'm only working with ftp & cpanel

Comment: You must need SSH access to fix this issue. Get access to SSH and I will help you out from this

Comment: thank you, i i have been trying this ssh access but i couldn't ... i will check and i will refer. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps.

clear `/var/cache , /var/generate, var/page_cache`

In your command prompt goto Magento root:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade.

bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Set permission to /var and /pub files and folder and check it.

Hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i can't use any commands ... i tried using ssh and the server is refusing

Comment: once ssh connect you can check and let me know

Comment: i'm still trying to ssh ... can you believe it ??? stupid host company

Comment: try like that it will helpful for you without connect ssh  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125064/how-to-install-module-magento-2-dont-need-run-command-line-bin-magento-setupup :)

Comment: i have ssh working finally but memory is 256MB i can't setup nor compile ... the hosting company changed my limit to 1024 but still i'm getting the same size 256MB when i check php limit via ssh

Comment: did you checked in phpinfo it is changed?

Comment: which file you mean ?? php_ini

Comment: Did you checked memory limit affected . Yes PHP.ini

Comment: after doing all the commands ..... nothing is changed ... still same errors of can't finding resources .... any ideas ???