# How to Run magento 2 command without connect putty?

Tags: magento2, ssh, command

When our Magento 2 on live server and we require to enable disable modules, flush cache , deploy static files etc ,we need to configure SSH.

but now not connect my putty so how to run all command

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Create a file in your Root 'commands.php', add commands you want to run in system() function in php file.

**2.** Run it by URL like : your-site-url/commands.php

```
  <?php
   system('php bin/magento cache:flush'); // for cache flush 
   system('php bin/magento setup:upgrade'); // for setup upgrade
   system('php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy'); // for static content deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple "test.php" in your root directory and put the code as mentioned in below post.

> [How to install module magento 2 don't need run command line bin/magento setup:upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125064/how-to-install-module-magento-2-dont-need-run-command-line-bin-magento-setupup/125090#125090)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perfect solution. Even if system() and shell_exec() and other commands are disabled from server due to security reasons, this script will help you to execute commands.

Note : It will not give any output but it will execute the command successfully.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$k[0]='bin/magento';
$k[1]='setup:upgrade'; // You can change command as you want like setup:static-content:deploy, cache:status etc.
$_SERVER['argv']=$k;
try {
$handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
$application = new Magento\Framework\Console\Cli('Magento CLI');
$application->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
while ($e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
echo $e->getTraceAsString();
echo "\n\n";
$e = $e->getPrevious();
}
}
?>
```